# How can I make the Jpanel to fill the remaining space remaining inside another panel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I started out with Swing a few days ago and I was trying to make a UI for a text editor like the one I've attached below
[Sample UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csuxu.png)

This might be a stupid question but I've made the toolbar and added a border but when I am trying to add the drawing pad it's not filing up the rest of the space?
[My UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va4Z7.png)

Here is the code, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text Editor");
        GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        GraphicsConfiguration config = graphicsDevice.getDefaultConfiguration();
        frame.setSize(config.getBounds().getSize());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        menuBar(frame);
        sketchPad(frame);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void menuBar(JFrame frame){
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file= new JMenu("File");
        String[] fileItems = {"New Tab","New Window","Open","Save","Save As","Save All", "Page Setup","Print","Close Tab","Close Window","Exit"};
        for(String item:fileItems){
            JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(item);
            file.add(menuItem);
        }
        menuBar.add(file);

        JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
        String[] editItems = {"Undo","Cut","Copy","Paste","Delete","Go To","Select All","Time/Date"};
        for(String item:editItems){
            JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(item);
            edit.add(menuItem);
        }
        menuBar.add(edit);

        JMenu review = new JMenu("Review");
        String[] reviewItems = {"Zoom","Status Bar","Word Wrap"};
        for(String item:reviewItems){
            if(item.equals("Zoom")){
                JMenu subMenu = new JMenu("Zoom");
                JMenuItem in,out,setDefault;
                in = new JMenuItem("Zoom In");
                subMenu.add(in);
                out = new JMenuItem("Zoom Out");
                subMenu.add(out);
                setDefault = new JMenuItem("Default");
                subMenu.add(setDefault);
                review.add(subMenu);
            }else {
                JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(item);
                review.add(menuItem);
            }
        }
        menuBar.add(review);
        
        JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
        String[] helpItems = {"Help","About"};
        for(String item:helpItems){
            JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(item);
            help.add(menuItem);
        }
        menuBar.add(help);
        
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }

    public static void sketchPad(JFrame frame){
        JPanel sketchPad = new JPanel();
        sketchPad.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        sketchPad.add(new JLabel("Sketch Pad"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel toolBar = new JPanel();
        toolBar.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        toolBar.add(new JButton("Rectangle"));
        toolBar.add(new JButton("Circle"));
        toolBar.add(new JButton("Line"));
        toolBar.add(new JButton("Triangle"));
        toolBar.add(new JButton("Pentagon"));
        toolBar.add(new JButton("Clear"));
        sketchPad.add(toolBar,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel drawingPad = new JPanel();
        drawingPad.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        sketchPad.add(drawingPad,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        sketchPad.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        frame.add(sketchPad,BorderLayout.EAST);
    }
}
```

I have tried using the setMinimumSize, setSize, getPreferedSize methods, but nothing seems to work. If I change the layout, it messes up everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefer adding `drawingPad` at the center.
As you need both a label and a toolbar at north add both in a dedicated panel.

```
public static void sketchPad(JFrame frame){
    JPanel toolBar = new JPanel();
    toolBar.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    toolBar.add(new JButton("Rectangle"));
    toolBar.add(new JButton("Circle"));
    toolBar.add(new JButton("Line"));
    toolBar.add(new JButton("Triangle"));
    toolBar.add(new JButton("Pentagon"));
    toolBar.add(new JButton("Clear"));

    JPanel control = new JPanel();
    control.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    control.add(new JLabel("Sketch Pad"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
    control.add(toolBar,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  
    JPanel drawingPad = new JPanel();
    drawingPad.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    JPanel sketchPad = new JPanel();
    sketchPad.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    sketchPad.add(control,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    sketchPad.add(drawingPad,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    sketchPad.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    frame.add(sketchPad,BorderLayout.EAST);
}
```

[image: New layout]

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

I rearranged your code to get the following GUI.

[image: Example]

When creating a Swing GUI, you work from the inside out.  You set the size of the various Swing components, and let the `JFrame` size itself by packing the components.

If the user wants to maximize the GUI, there's a rectangle in the upper right for that purpose.  Make your GUI as small as possible.

Get out of `static` methods.  Method names should be a verb-noun combination.

Group like code together.  You had `JFrame` method calls all over your code, making them hard to find.

Create a separate method or class for each `JPanel`.  That way, you can easily experiment with different Swing layouts.

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TextEditor implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TextEditor());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text Editor");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());

        frame.add(createDrawingPad(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createSketchPad(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        String[] fileItems = { "New Tab", "New Window", "Open", "Save",
                "Save As", "Save All", "Page Setup", "Print", "Close Tab",
                "Close Window", "Exit" };
        for (String item : fileItems) {
            JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(item);
            file.add(menuItem);
        }
        menuBar.add(file);

        JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
        String[] editItems = { "Undo", "Cut", "Copy", "Paste", "Delete",
                "Go To", "Select All", "Time/Date" };
        for (String item : editItems) {
            JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(item);
            edit.add(menuItem);
        }
        menuBar.add(edit);

        JMenu review = new JMenu("Review");
        String[] reviewItems = { "Zoom", "Status Bar", "Word Wrap" };
        for (String item : reviewItems) {
            if (item.equals("Zoom")) {
                JMenu subMenu = new JMenu("Zoom");
                JMenuItem in, out, setDefault;
                in = new JMenuItem("Zoom In");
                subMenu.add(in);
                out = new JMenuItem("Zoom Out");
                subMenu.add(out);
                setDefault = new JMenuItem("Default");
                subMenu.add(setDefault);
                review.add(subMenu);
            } else {
                JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(item);
                review.add(menuItem);
            }
        }
        menuBar.add(review);

        JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
        String[] helpItems = { "Help", "About" };
        for (String item : helpItems) {
            JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(item);
            help.add(menuItem);
        }
        menuBar.add(help);

        return menuBar;
    }
    
    public JPanel createDrawingPad() {
        JPanel drawingPad = new JPanel();
        drawingPad.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        drawingPad.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        
        return drawingPad;
    }
    
    public JPanel createSketchPad() {
        JPanel sketchPad = new JPanel();
        sketchPad.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        sketchPad.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        
        sketchPad.add(new JLabel("Sketch Pad"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        sketchPad.add(createToolBar(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        return sketchPad;
    }
    
    public JPanel createToolBar() {
        JPanel toolBar = new JPanel();
        toolBar.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        toolBar.add(new JButton("Rectangle"));
        toolBar.add(new JButton("Circle"));
        toolBar.add(new JButton("Line"));
        toolBar.add(new JButton("Triangle"));
        toolBar.add(new JButton("Pentagon"));
        toolBar.add(new JButton("Clear"));
        
        return toolBar;
    }
    
}
```